# Android 6.0.1 application auto start after boot

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver, android-6.0.1-marshmallow

I want to start my `MainActivity` right after device boot. I tried multiple solutions but no one works. Currently, I have this.

*AndroidManifest.xml*

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<receiver android:name="installer.common.InstallerBroadcastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

*InstallerBroadcastReceiver.kt*

```
class InstallerBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val i = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        i.putExtra("test", 1)
        context.startActivity(i)
    }
}
```

*MainActivity.kt*

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.main)
    if (intent.hasExtra("test")) {
        someMethodHere()
    }
}
```

Any suggestion on what can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is some problem with device (zkteco), i get this error `I/BackgroundManagerService: prevent from boot complete broadcast: com.mypackagename`

On other devices i tried, it was working.

Answer (score 0):

try to split your `intent-filter`

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: hi, unfortunatelly it did not help still not working